# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I am new to Rails and am making a simple Rails app in which I am doing a modal popup for user login in. My code is below.

**App/Controller/Sessions:**

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # respond_to :html, :json
  # before_action :check_user_session, only: [:new]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate(auth_options)
    if self.resource.present?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in)
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      yield resource if block_given?
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

**My `new.js.haml` file:**

```
$("#login-modal").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'new')}");
$("#exampleModal").modal();
```

I am getting this error when I click the sign in button.

Comment: Might have something to do with `class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController` (your first line). I don't know much about ruby, but seems like `<` is unexpected there

Comment: no that is not the issue with     class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController because this is my controller and it is inherrited by devise

Comment: Well then, don't you miss an `end` at the end ?

Comment: can you share you `new.html.erb` or the sign_in form?

Comment: Can you post the full error trace ?

Answer (score 1):

change file `new.js.haml` to `new.js.erb` with following code:

```
$("#login-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'new') %>");
$("#exampleModal").modal();
```

Comment: have you changed file extension to `js.erb`?